# Matching not (0 or more '0's) with JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a bit stuck with writing a regex on JavaScript. I want to write a regex to match a string that is

- if it contains only digits, consisting of **NOT ONLY** 0 or more '0's ;
- if it doesn't only contain digits, starting with either of these letters: tysjod ;

Test cases for matching:

- "yes"
- "1"
- "1010"
- " 0 "

Test cases for not matching:

- "no"
- "0"
- "00"
- ""

I have written this so far but it isn't quite right, as it doesn't pass all the test cases. I don't know what is wrong.

```
return value.match(/!(^0*$)|(^[tysjod])/i);
```

Can I wrap `^` and `$` in the brackets like this? Just wondering...

Comment: Requirments are not very clear.

Comment: _"it isn't quite right"_ Please be exact about what "is not quite right" means.

Comment: Doesn't match all the test cases?

Comment: *"if it doesn't only contain digits, starting with either of these letters*"  huh?  Is this "it should match if there are non-digits and starts with one of tysjod"?

Comment: @fdomn-m yes, for non-digit-only part, i think that works, it is the zero's part that is not working, i think

Comment: Better off using multiple regex to detect the different pass/fail cases. Can still have one expression using logic fall through like `result = a || b || c`, unless they need to be handled separately.

Comment: The zeros part doesn't work because `!` is trying to match a literal `!`; it doesn't mean "not".

Comment: Could you clarify why " 0 " (space, zero, space) should match when it does not contain only digits and does not start with a letter among `[tysjod]`?

Comment: ^^ for this reason this question is ambiguous. Why is no clarification coming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
/^(?:[tysjod].*|(?!0+$) *\d+ *$)/i
```

See the regex demo. Replace the regular spaces with `\s` if you plan to allow any kind of whitespace in the string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HkAcRD/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[tysjod].*|(?!0+$) *\d+ *$)` - two alternatives:

  - `[tysjod].*` - a letter from the `tysjod` set and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (replace `.` with `[^]` if you want to match any characters, or add `/s` flag)
  - `|` - or
  - `(?!0+$) *\d+ *$` - make sure there are no one or more `0` chars till the end of the string, and if there is none, match zero or more spaces, then one or more digits and then zero or more spaces, followed with the end of string.